What is the difference between ':.mf' and ':.n' in Python?
When I enter :.4f in PyCharm, it indeed outputs with 4 decimal places. However, when I enter :.4, it only retains 3 decimal places. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. I would like to get specific differences and meanings between these two methods, rather than being told a solution.

For full details, you should read the format spec docs.

See the table after "The available presentation types for float and Decimal values are:" in Format Specification Mini-Language for the meaning of f vs no precision flag

As explained the linked dupe and docs, .4 means 4 significant digits, while .4f means 4 digits after the decimal

Are you asking about format strings, i.e. strings with an f prefix or used with the .format method? "When I enter :.4f in PyCharm" doesn’t make all that much sense.
